# Any way to run the original Anno 1503 discs on Windows 10 64-bit?

Tags: anno-1503

I bought Anno 1503, and the first disc installs fine. When I put the second game disc in, it loads up the start menu, but when I click 'Start' it loads for a couple seconds and then crashes.
I've tried Compatibility Mode, running as an admin, and literally everything I've been able to find online.
I don't really want to use a virtual machine or have to buy it on GoG or Uplay. Or does anyone know of any patches that will help it run on windows 10

Comment: If you tried literally everything, I'm afraid we can't be of much help. But, for completeness' sake, does it give you an error you can post here, either as screenshot or as text?

Comment: nope no errors at all also you can still recommend ways to try fix it if u want cause I've only tried stuff i was able to find

Comment: You could have a look in the *event viewer* perhaps? Might be something in Application (or even System) logs.

Comment: How do I view the event viewer? 

Comment: @RedTheAnimal press the windows key and type 'Event Viewer'. Check the application log under 'Windows Logs'.

Comment: Ok i'm there but what am i looking for?

Comment: Just so you know: https://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Anno_1503 "SafeDisc retail DRM no longer functions properly on Windows Vista and later"

Comment: @TylerKropp That sounds like the start of an answer.